# How to display content in an infowindow specific to a marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I created a google maps (api v3) with the number of markers depending on the search results. When I click a marker, it opens an infowindow. What's the best way to have that infowindow show information associated to its marker? The information related to all the markers is in a json object I receive from an ajax request.

```
for (i=0; i < result.point.length; i++) {
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.proint[i].Latitude,result.point[i].Longitude);                                    
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        title: i.toString()
                        //map: map
                    });
                    markersArray.push(marker);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: 'specific information associated to the marker clicked'
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function(event) {
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

Comment: Link to live code would be valuable.

Comment: Do you want multiple info windows or just one? The way your code is now, a new info window is created for each marker, however only one, the last one created, will ever be shown. If your intention is to only have one, then you should move the creation of it out of the for loop.

Comment: I agree more code would be helpful, at least the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks for point that out. Yes, my intention is to only have one. Here's the json object: $arr = array();
            foreach ($points as $row) {
                array_push($arr, array('Address' => $row->getAddress(),'Latitude' => $row->getLatitude(), 'Longitude' => $row->getLongitude(),'PublicTransportation' => $row->getPublicTransportation(),'Name' => $row->getName(),'Description' => $row->getDescription()
                ));
            }
            die(json_encode(array('point' => $arr)));

Comment: Did you figure this out? Did any of the answers help? Please mark an answer as helpful if it was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what it is you are trying to do. Where/ what content are you trying to load?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(event, index) {
  return function(){
  infowindow.content = markersArray[index].yourcontent;
  // or
  infowindow.content = yourcontentarray[index];
  infowindow.open(map,this);
  }
})(marker,i));
```

Make sure you declare your marker and infowindow variables outside of a function.

Comment: There are several flaws to this code. First, **event** is an argument of the IIFE when it should be an argument of the returned function instead. Here event actually equals the passed in marker, not the event. The marker does not even need to be passed in. Next, you should use the setContent method of the infowindow instead of setting the content property directly. While setting the property will work, it bypasses the KVO benefits of MVCObject. For example, using setContent will trigger the content_changed event of the infowindow, setting the property directly will not.

Answer (score 6):

Create only 1 infoWindow as suggested above.

The content store inside the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        title: i.toString(),
                        //set your content here
                        content:'your specific content'
                        //map: map
                    });
```

The opening of the window:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function(event) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should move the the creation of the infoWindow out of the for loop.

Next, change where you attach the click event to this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function(content) {
    return function(event){
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
}(WHATEVER_THE_CONTENT_SHOULD_BE_FOR_THIS_MARKER));
```

You want to use **this** instead of **marker**. **this** will refer to the object the event took place on, while **marker** will refer to the last marker created.

Comment: The following link was posted by someone else. It's a perfect example of what I'm trying to achieve. http://updates.orbitz.com/

Comment: The above should get you what you want. If not can you provide updated code? Also, a sample of the JSON in JavaScript format instead of PHP would be more helpful.

Comment: It eventually works! synthax error... Shane, puckhead, I tremendously appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the syntax error? And please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your example (proint) At the top of you loop:

```
for (i=0; i < result.point.length; i++) {
   var info_window_content = result.point[i].Latitude + '<br />';
   info_window_content += result.point[i].Longitue + '<br />';
   // etc for any value in you json object
   // create your marker as is.
     ...
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info_window_content
                });
  // etc, etc.
```

You do need to add an eventListener to each marker, as you are doing.  I don't see any problem with that.
Except I'd use infoWindow.open(map, marker) vs. this.

There is probably a more efficient way to do it, i.e. after infoWindow.open(); infoWindow.setContent(info_window_content)

Comment: Thanks Eric! I used 'this' in the first place so that the infowindow would be positioned based on the marker. I implemented your solution but might be doing something wrong as the content remains static. Looking for a way to load the content associated to the marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works I tested it already

```
// Add markers

   for (i=0; i < result.point.length; i++) {
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.proint[i].Latitude, result.point[i].Longitude);                                    
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        title: i.toString()
                        //map: map
                    });                    

    // marker info start
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    (function (marker, result.point[i]) {
                    // add click event
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,  'click',  function() {
                    var infoContent: "specific information associated to the marker clicked"
                    });
        infoWindow.setContent(infoContent);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

    // selected marker 4 infowindow 
    (marker, result.point[i]);

       markersArray.push(marker);
      }
```